# Syntax Error in Simple Case Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

Trying to use a Case Statement for the first time, which is why the code is so small/simple. Returning a syntax error, supposedly with my table name `[Impact]`.

```
    Select Case [Impact]
    Case Is = 0
    [New Impact] = "1"
    End Select
```

Any assistance is appreciated. I've looked around for solutions, but most of the time answers are related to something else in their code, and not anything I have in this small test code.

Comment: Access uses `switch`, not `case`.

Comment: it might be "simple" code, but what you have written doesn't make sense as a `CASE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Access Case statement can **only** be used in **VBA** code.

The structure is like so:

```
Select Case test_expression    
   Case condition_1
      result_1
   Case condition_n
      result_n    
   [Case Else
      result_else]    
End Select
```

My guess, is you missed the part about using this through VBA only.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, the logic one would normally used is:

```
Select iif([Impact] = 0, "1", NULL) as [New Impact]
```

You could use `switch()` as well, but that seems like overkill.